How to derive the integral form of Airy function
enter image description here
Context: Considering the ODE $\frac{d^2\psi}{du^2}=u\psi$, through Fourier Transformation, we obtain the solution $$\psi(u)=\int \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi}e^{ik^3/3}e^{iku}$$
Now I will integrate this solution by two contour C1 and C2 shown in the figure to get two different functions Ai(u) and Bi(u) while the expression of functions are
$$Ai(u)=\int_{C1} \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi}e^{ik^3/3}e^{iku}\text{ and }Bi(u)=-i\int_{C1} \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi}e^{ik^3/3}e^{iku}+2i\int_{C2} \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi}e^{ik^3/3}e^{iku}$$
Questions:

Contour C1: real axis, let $k=t\in R$, then the integral becomes $$\int \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi}e^{i(t^3/3-tu)} $$ but I do not know how to complete this computation so that it becomes the final form $$Ai(u)=1/\pi\int_0^\infty \text{d}k \cos(k^3/3+ku)$$ while $e^{i(t^3/3-tu)}$ is entirely analytic.
Contour C2: the same problem as C1, $C2=t\in(-\infty,0]$ and $iv,v\in(-\infty,0)$. I can integrate the half imaginary axis, but how it becomes
$$Bi(u)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\text{d}k(e^{-ik^3/3+ku}+sin(k^3/3+ku))$$

